# From 12V to 325v - 400v DC DC converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, safety, high-voltage

I am having some problems designing a HV DC DC converter. I have 12v input. The device that needs such high voltages is a UVTRON sensor from Hamamatsu. The devices need a supply voltage of 325V to 400V (+-25V). The datasheet can be found [here](http://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/etd/UVtron_TPT1034E.pdf). Because it is unsure which sensor we will be using we need to easily change from one to another, soldering is allowed. In the final design it will be fixed.

The required power is very low, and as such designs I find floating on the web are not always great for this application because of safety.

My current approach is using a transformer (750311468 from Wurth Elektronik for example) and using a mosfet + controller (which I already have) to convert the DC signal to a square wave. However with such high voltages I am unsure if the approach I am taking is right. Also the dangers involved makes this a big risk. I do not want the transformer unleash all of it's current in a saturated state on a person.

I also looked at the Cockcroft–Walton topology but in simulations it seems impossible to get the voltage accurate enough.

Do you guys know of topologies which give me a voltage between 300V and 400V and are "safe" to use in this application?

Comment: Under "related products" there are ready-made power supplies designed to supply that high voltage you need. Why not use one of those ? Designing such a HV supply requires time and experience.

Comment: If you tear apart a single use camera with flash, you can have a source of 300+ volts running from a single AA cell. Remove the big 120uF capacitor and replace it with 0.1uF for safety. Probably not much different in topology from the proper supply that you can buy from UVTRON! Neither this nor a Cockcroft Walton will get you an accurate or stable voltage open loop, it will need feedback. I am sure the proper supply from UVTRON uses feedback to control its output voltage.

Comment: 400 V is not high voltage. :-)

Comment: @FakeMoustache I know there are ready made supplies available, however these are more pricey than we would like. Also the form factor could be optimized for our device. There are also several other factors which makes it better for us to implement the UVTRON! in our complete design.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly trivial design as far as power supply designs go, if you know how and no more dangerous to use,  than a neon indicator tube.  Suitable skill and care is still needed,

I strongly suggest you follow the Manufacturer's advice in the datasheet.

Frankly your incorrect assumptions, so far tell me your best bet is the miniature supply board and cables from the Mfg.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can see I'm in over my head here. Currently we are using those DC-DC converters. Would you like to point out the incorrect assumptions, because the only thing I learned now is that I should use the reference board.

Comment: You start reading specs and understand all your requirements are given in published specs. Safety, Power voltage size.then get cost. Since you have not stated your requirements even if it is portable or not, how many you are buying, your budget etc, to start making a list of "must have" and nice to have. You test the potential sensors 1st and then design/choose/buy  PSU needed after unless you already know.  "I also looked at the Cockcroft–Walton topology but in simulations it seems imploosible to get the voltage accurate enough." is false. (one just has to understand Z ratios and load err.

Answer (score 0):

> However with such high voltages I am unsure if the approach I am
>   taking is right. Also the dangers involved makes this a big risk. I do
>   not want the transformer unleash all of it's current in a saturated
>   state on a person.

Bottom line is this - an unprotected power supply that provides 400 volts at currents up to 200 mA is lethal: -

[image]

So you have to make sure it is safe by using interlocks and isolation.

> Do you guys know of any topologies which give me a voltage between
>   300V and 400V and are "safe" to use in this application?

No, the supply is dangerous, you have to engineer safety by restricting access, using double insulation techniques, correctly rating components and using interlocks. You might also consider using something similar to a residual current device (GFCI in the US) to trip the power should someone take current due to touching a live part.

Comment: The tube is connected via 10MOhm to the HVPSU in the application note so the constant current is low while these high currents are the withstand limits of the tube when it pulses on during operation fed from the 220pF holding capacitor.  I do not think the PSU _has_ to be very dangerous but certainly can be if it can source more current than is needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar problem than a nixie tube power supply (180VDC) and can be achieved with a switching voltage regulator.

[Popular designs use a MAX1771](http://desmith.net/NMdS/Electronics/NixiePSU.html).

**Note:** it's not safe.